# jdk1.8 StringBuffer source code method without synchronized keyword

Tags: java, stringbuffer

```
@Override
public StringBuffer insert(int dstOffset, CharSequence s) {
  // Note, synchronization achieved via invocations of other StringBuffer methods
  // after narrowing of s to specific type
  // Ditto for toStringCache clearing
  super.insert(dstOffset, s);
  return this;
}
```

This method and several other methods of StringBuffer have no "synchronized" keyword. The comment says synchronization achieved via invocations of other StringBuffer methods after narrowing of s to specific type. How is the synchronization achieved without "synchronized" keyword?

Comment: That `super.insert` call ends up calling a different overload, which is itself overridden in StringBuffer by a synchronized method.

Comment: To be clear it calls either the `insert(int dstOffset, String s)` or `insert(int dstOffset, CharSequence s, int start, int end)` on  `StringBuilder` depending on the type of value provided as `s` (which are both synchronized methods).

Comment: Ah! I see! It is the mechanism of method overriden. Thanks!

Comment: @MrR to me, that counts as an answer, a bit thin, but still counts.